# Pyment ругается на букву И

Tags: python, кодировка

Как сделать, чтобы pyment не прерывался на букве И с ошибкой?

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 865: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Проверьте кодировку строки, и используйте в операциях соответствующую кодировку. Вангую, что Вам нужна cp1251

Comment: @Namerek pyment на вход получает файл модуля питона. Модуль в стандартной для питона кодировке utf-8

Comment: и всетаки попробуйте https://charset-normalizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/getstarted.html#basic-usage